# Error in parsing data on R-Studio while running ADF

Tags: r, rstudio

I cannot seem to get past or understand what is wrong with this error while trying to run the ADF (Augmented Dickey Fuller) test on R-Studio. Will appreciate comments.

```
library(AER)
library("dynlm", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.2")
x<-read.table("C://R Files/protein.csv", header=T, sep=",")
"adf" <- function(x,k = 0, int = TRUE, trend = FALSE){
     require(dynlm)
     dx <- diff(x)
     formula <- paste("dx ~ L(x)")
     if(k > 0)
         formula <- paste(formula,"  L(dx,1:k)")
     if(trend){
         s <- time(x)
         t <- ts(s - s[1],start = s[1],freq = frequency(x))
         formula <- paste(formula,"  t")
     }
     if(!int) formula <- paste(formula," - 1")
     summary(dynlm(as.formula(formula)))
 }

a<-ts(x$a)
adf(a, k=1, int=T, trend=T)
```

The error message that I get after this is :

Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  :1:13: unexpected symbol
1: dx ~ L(x)   L
                ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be this:
`formula <- paste(formula,"  L(dx,1:k)")`

You can't just add something to a model. Try doing:
`formula <- paste(formula,"+ L(dx,1:k)")`
and see if that helps. If not you might want to share the contents of protein.csv so I can try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: that fixed the problem. Thanks Erik !

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help Adriel. Would you also consider accepting my answer? Thanks.